# SplashScreen com rotas nomeadas

Tags: flutter, dart, rotas

Estou usando o pacote Splashscreen no meu app.
Quero que na tela do splashscreen o app identifique que já existe um usuário logado que foi feito com firebase. No entanto junto a chamada da rota é necessário passar argumento com os dados do usuário logado que pego no controller, porém o navigateAfterSeconds do splashscreen aceita apenas String ou Widget. Como faço para chamar a rota junto do argumento neste splashscreen?

```
SplashScreen(
          seconds: 5,
          gradientBackground: LinearGradient(
            begin: Alignment.topRight,
            end: Alignment.bottomLeft, 
            colors: [Colors.blue, Colors.blueAccent],
          ),
          navigateAfterSeconds: // AQUI VAI O RETORNO DA FUNÇÃO ISLOGGED, 
          loaderColor: Colors.transparent,
        ),
```

---

```
class InitialController extends GetxController {
  final box = GetStorage('habito_invest_app');

  
  // Verifica se já existe usuário logado
  dynamic isLogged() async {
    if(box.hasData('auth')){
      UserModel user = UserModel(
        id: box.read('auth')['id'],
        email: box.read('auth')['email'],
        name: box.read('auth')['name'],
        urlimage: box.read('auth')['urlimage']
      );
      return Routes.HOME; //preciso passar o user junto
    } else {
      return Routes.LOGIN;
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu resolvi o problema deixando de usar o package e implementando a a função onReady no Controller, dessa forma conseguir setar o usuário na rota, algo que o package não deixava. Dessa forma funcionou perfeitamente.

```
class SplashScreenController extends GetxController {
  final box = GetStorage('habito_invest_app');

@override
void onReady() {
 Timer(
   Duration(seconds: 3),
   () => isLogged()
 );
 super.onReady();
}

// Verifica se já existe usuário logado
void isLogged(){     
if(box.hasData('auth')){
  UserModel user = UserModel(
    id: box.read('auth')['id'],
    email: box.read('auth')['email'],
    name: box.read('auth')['name'],
    urlimage: box.read('auth')['urlimage']
  );
  Get.offAllNamed(Routes.HOME, arguments: user);
  } else {
    Get.offAllNamed(Routes.LOGIN);
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você poderia criar um Singleton de um UserController que possui um objeto User, o qual você poderia recuperar em outras partes do seu app e usá-lo para setar e recuperá-lo na sua Home.

UserController {
User user = User();

// métodos de usuario....

}

main (){
Get.put(UserController());
}

final UserController userController = Get find();

userController.user = UserFromStorage();

return Routes.Home;

E na Home você pode recuperar os dados do usuario assim:

final UserController userController = Get find();

Text(userController.user.name)